# Sum all documents for a field within an array

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I just want to know about count in mongodb through php. In this case, I have document looks like this:

```
{
"_id": 1,
"item" : [
{ "name": "foo",
"price": 1000
},
{ "name": "bar",
"price": 500
}
]
}

{
"_id": 2,
"item" : [
{ "name": "foo",
"price": 1000
}
]
}
```

When I was using the following code like this:

```
$connection = new MongoClient();
$db = $connection->shop;
$collection = $db->sales;
$pipe = array(array('$unwind'=>'$item'),
array('$group'=>array('_id'=>array('_id'=>'1','result'=>array('$sum'=>'$item.price')))));
$total = $collection->aggregateCursor($pipe);
foreach ($total as $dc){
$total_price = $dc['result'];
}
echo "<b>Result of all this customer : </b>".$total_price."<br>";
```

The result of that code is looks like the result of all document such as:

```
Result of all this customer : 2500
```

In other side as I wish, the result has counted for each id not for count all of document that I had. What's wrong with that code ?

I hope, the result of this case:

```
Result of all this customer : 1500
```

Please someone help me...

The following answer that I found, maybe it will be helping someone who had same trouble.

```
$connection = new MongoClient();
    $db = $connection->shop;
    $collection = $db->sales;
    $pipe = array(array('$unwind'=>'$item'),array('$match'=>array('_id'=>'1')), array('$group'=>array('_id'=>array('_id'=>'1','result'=>array('$sum'=>'$item.price')))));
    $total = $collection->aggregateCursor($pipe);
    foreach ($total as $dc){
    $total_price = $dc['result'];
    }
    echo "<b>Result of all this customer : </b>".$total_price."<br>";
```

Added $match for sorting an id, and that query will check only embedded document with targeted id.

Comment: Simply one pipeline stage. `[[ '$group =>  [ '_id' => NULL, 'total_price' => [ '$sum' => [ '$sum' => '$item.price' ] ] ] ]]` using modern PHP notation of `[]` instead of `array()` here.

Comment: Why you didn't take $unwind and directly to $group ? @NeilLunn

Comment: Because you do not need it and it slows things down, considerably. Modern MongoDB releases can apply `$sum` with an array argument. So `'$item.price'` returns an array of "only" the `'price'` field values, that we pass to `$sum` to get the total in that array, Then `$sum` is used again to "accumulate" for the actual `$group` statement. Hence the double use of `$sum`. I know I've answered this question elsewhere so I am just searching for that.

Comment: @NeilLunn - you seem to know your way around mongoDB, I'm learning it and not entirely pleased with it,.  Have 112 Million rows so it's been a challenge.

Comment: It couldn't work sir :( I added (') in $group that you might forget, it still doesn't work. What should I do ? @NeilLunn

Comment: Thank you for your appreciate @ArtisticPhoenix, Do you know what kind of $unwind, $group, and anything else for solving my problem ?

Comment: Moved to an answer so you can clearly see the syntax. This works perfectly in all releases since MongoDB 3.2

Answer (score 0):

You only need a single [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage here since you can actually use [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) for both the array items and the "accumulator" for the grouping:

```
$result = $collection->aggregate([
  [ '$group' => [ 
    '_id' => null,
    'total_price' => [ '$sum' => [ '$sum' => '$item.price' ] ] 
  ]]
])
```

That's a lot more efficient than using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) which should be avoided when you don't actually need it.

In the old way using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) you actually point to the field:

```
$result = $collection->aggregate([
  [ '$unwind' => '$item' ],
  [ '$group' => [ 
    '_id' => null,
    'total_price' => [ '$sum' => '$item.price' ]
  ]]
])
```

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work. There was blank (no output). Is there way to solve this problem ? And I don't know what you mean that you did't let _id to fulfilled some id to get only group of each document.

Comment: Look at my post, I had found the answer. Thank you for trying to help me. Keep it up for helping everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the aggregation. If you remove match stage, it will give a sum for every user.

```
> db.product.aggregate(
...    [
...       {
...          $match: {'_id':{ '$eq': 1}}
...       },
...       {
...           $unwind: '$item'
...       },
...       {
...         $group : {
...            _id : '$_id',
...            totalPrice: { $sum: '$item.price' },
...         }
...       }
...    ]
... )
{ "_id" : 1, "totalPrice" : 1500 }
```